# UIImage not fully loaded when retrieving UNNotificationAttachment

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationattachment, unnotificationscontentextension

I have a NotificationContentExtension and want to display the NotificationAttachment in a UIImageView. That works fine but when I extend the push notification (so the NotificationContentExtension loads) it seems like the image is not fully loaded. It has a grey rectangle in the bottom right corner which was not there when I displayed it with the NotificationServiceExtension.

This is the didReceive method in my NotificationContentExtension:

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    let content = notification.request.content;
    
    self.name.text = content.title
    self.subject.text = content.subtitle
    self.body.text = content.body
    
    if let attachment = content.attachments.first {
         if attachment.url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: attachment.url.path)
            attachment.url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
         }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the access to the resource got stopped before the UIImage was fully loaded. Using DispatchQueue and loading the UIImage with imageData solved this for me.

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    self.name.text = notification.request.content.title
    self.subject.text = notification.request.content.subtitle
    self.body.text = notification.request.content.body
    
    let imageUrl: URL? = notification.request.content.attachments.first!.url
    
    if let url = imageUrl, url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            var imageData: Data?
            do {
                imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            } catch let error {
                print(error);
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            }
        }
    }
}
```